# Django serializer Imagefield to get full URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am beginner to Django and currently, I can construct model like this.

[image]

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars')
```

serializers.py

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id','name','price', 'photo')
```

views.py

```
class CarView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    def get(self, request):
        car = Car.objects.all()
        serializer = CarSerializer(car)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

For photo, it doesn't show full URL. How can I show full URL?

Comment: Unless your MEDIA_ROOT is within your static folder, there is no direct URL to the file.

Comment: try SerializerMethodField ; http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Django is not providing an absolute URL to the image stored in a `models.ImageField` (at least if you don't include the domain name in the [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL); including the domain is not recommended, except of you are hosting your media files on a different server (e.g. aws)).

However, you can modify your serializer to return the absolute URL of your photo by using a custom [`serializers.SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). In this case, your serializer needs to be changed as follows:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id','name','price', 'photo_url') 

    def get_photo_url(self, car):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        photo_url = car.photo.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)
```

Also make sure that you have set Django's [`MEDIA_ROOT`and `MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) parameters and that you can access a photo via your browser `http://localhost:8000/path/to/your/image.jpg`.

As piling pointed out, you need to add the request while initialising the serializer in your views.py:

```
def my_view(request):
    …
    car_serializer = CarSerializer(car, context={"request": request})
    car_serializer.data
```

Comment: Do I need to modify in views.py as well? I got error after I change your one in Serializers.py.

 __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Not sure if you can add a QuerySet into the Serializer class. Can you try it with one element only ```serializer = CarSerializer(car[0])``` ?

Comment: I still have that error though. I uploaded my project here. In case, if it is necessary  to check setting also.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/wj3ey2pfx3ygyf5/todoapi.zip

Comment: looks like you placed the ```photo_url``` inside the ```Meta``` class. Place it one scope above and it should do the trick.

Comment: If not try this ; serialized_car = CarSerializer(Car, context={"request": request})

Comment: As it is shown in my answer. Additionally @piling provides the right direction for modifications of the views.py.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks both of you. 
But for photo_url, I need to change like this. 

    photo_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_photo_url')

Comment: I was missing the request object. Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

For future visitors, there is no need to add another field to the serializer if the view method already returns a serialized object. The only thing required is to add the context since it is needed to generate hyperlinks, as stated in the [drf documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

```
@list_route()
def my_view(self, request):
    qs = Object.objects.all()
    return Response(MySerializer(qs, many=True, context={'request': request}).data)
```

Comment: When using django rest framework views, the context is passed along automatically. If you then use nested serializers without passing the context through, you end up in a confusing situation. So this is very good to know!

Comment: I'm using django rest framework, and this solution was required to output the fully qualfiied URL path.

Answer (score 23):

## Serializer class

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  photo_url = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
  class Meta:
      model = Car
      fields = ('id','name','price', 'photo_url')
```

## View

```
class CarView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = Car.objects.all()

        serializer = CarSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={"request":request})

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 10):

It's better to use this code, due to the above code doesn't check the image is null able or not.

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      photo_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

      class Meta:
            model = Car
            fields = ('id','name','price', 'photo_url') 

      def get_photo_url(self, car):
            request = self.context.get('request')
            if photo and hasattr(photo, 'url'):
               photo_url = car.photo.url
               return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)
            else:
               return None
```

Answer (score 4):

serializers.py

```
 class BannerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        def get_image(self, obj):
            return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri( obj.image.url)
```

views.py

```
            banner = Banner.objects.all()
            banner_data = BannerSerializer(banner,many=True, context={'request': request})
            data = banner_data.data
            return Response({"data":data})
```

Comment: FYI: Good answer but this won't work for anything other than the default Django File Storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

I read the implement of the Serializer, and find the simplest way is to extends ImageField:

```py
from django.db import models

class ImageField(models.ImageField):
    def value_to_string(self, obj): # obj is Model instance, in this case, obj is 'Class'
        return obj.fig.url # not return self.url

class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # fig = models.ImageField(upload_to="classes")
    fig = ImageField(upload_to="classes") 

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self,"name")
```