# How to return the absolute path in Django RF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I upload the files to the server to specific folders, organized by projects.
(I forgot to mention that I use Docker)

On DB I save:

id

```
4
```

path

```
/var/local/vvv/project-files/project_2/v_5//r_4_C5R1ud0W8AQwnxa.jpg:large.jpeg
```

filename

```
r_4_C5R1ud0W8AQwnxa.jpg:large.jpeg
```

file_type

```
jpeg
```

How can I get the absolute path ?

Something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/r_4_C5R1ud0W8AQwnxa.jpg
```

The only thing I could do is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vv/download_resource/4
```

but it doesn't work for what i need.

Please HELP

My Model where are the images:

```
class Resource(utils.SafeDeleteModel):
    path      = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)  # just to define where to save to
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    added_on  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    added_by  = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    comment   = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django serialize imagefield to get full url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522768/django-serialize-imagefield-to-get-full-url)

Comment: Uh. It seems that you're using `CharField` to manage media. Is there any reason to do this manually instead of using `FileField` or `ImageField`? With `CharField`s you'll have to (re)implement things (e.g. path conversions) in your own code. Can you switch to e.g. `ImageField`s (that would be the most straightforward and clean approach) or there are barriers preventing you from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to serialize any field in Django RF, example:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    foo_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('image',)

    def get_thumbnail_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url
```

This probably will end up returning what you want.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if OP needs an absolute URL, he would need something like this:

```
def get_thumbnail_url(self, obj):
    url = obj.image.url
    request = self.context.get("request", None)
    if request is not None:
        url = request.build_absolute_uri(url)
    return url
```

Comment: it doesn't return what i want

Comment: Seems like you are not storing enough information to build an url like you want then