# How can I send images from Django Rest Api to a Vue SPA?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

I am developing a Vue.js 2.0 single page application with DRF REST api on the backend. I have images stored in filesystem and one of my models has a field called "image" containing the address of the image.

My model:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='boards/')
    safe_for_work = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Viewset:

```
class BoardViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = BoardSerializer

    def list(self, request,):
        queryset = Board.objects.filter()
        serializer = BoardSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Board.objects.filter()
        board = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = BoardSerializer(board)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When i call my endpoint from my Vue SPA, instead of getting the image, I only get the local url, for example `"/storage/boards/board1.jpg"`.

How can I access the actual image on my Vue page?

Ideally I would like to get a list of all the images from the endpoint and display them.

Comment: Do you want to get the **full** url or the base64 encoded image?

Comment: I wanted to know if it's possible to send the image and if it's a correct way of handling this problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522768/django-serialize-imagefield-to-get-full-url) solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

With this issue you must config in server (Django Rest) instead of Vue client. Config your serializer to display full path of image:

```
class BoardSerializer(ModelViewSet)
     image = FileField(source='image')
     class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'image',
            ...
        ]
```

Don't forget `context: { 'request': request }` in Viewset

```
def list(self, request,):
        queryset = Board.objects.filter()
        serializer = BoardSerializer(queryset, many=True, context: { 'request': request })
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Board.objects.filter()
        board = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = BoardSerializer(board, context: { 'request': request })
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Hope it helps!