# Django Rest Framework get a lookup field as a list of hyperlinks

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model **Album** and a model **Photo**, which references the first one through a **FireignKey** field. I want the **ModelSerializer** for model **Album** to return a list of hyperlinks to relate entries in model **Photo** through a lookup field, but I only get it to return a list of ids.

These are my models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Description"))
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='albums', verbose_name=_("Company"))
    access_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=_create_access_code, verbose_name=_("Internal Use"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Album")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Albums")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}] {} ({})".format(self.pk, self.name, self.company.id)

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='photos', verbose_name=_("Album"))
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Photo"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Photo")
        verbose_name_plural =_("Photos")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}] {}".format(self.pk, self.name)
```

And this is my serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = proxies.AlbumProxy
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'company', 'access_code', 'photos')
```

I want the field `photos` to return a list of hyperlinks, but I get a list of ids:

```
"id": 1,
"name": "Navidad 2018",
"description": "La primera",
"company": 1,
"access_code": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"photos": [
     11,
     10,
      7,
      6
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [HyperlinkedRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/#hyperlinking-our-api), something like this:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = proxies.AlbumProxy
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'name', 
            'description', 
            'company', 
            'access_code',  
            'photos'
        )

    photos = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        view_name='<your-photos-view-name>', 
        read_only=True
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your [photos full urls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35522768/10657880) you can declare a [Serializer Method Field](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to do something like this:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = proxies.AlbumProxy
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'company', 'access_code')

    def get_photos_url(self, obj):
        urls = []
        request = self.context.get('request')
        for photo in obj.photos:
            urls.append(request.build_absolute_uri(photo.url))
        return urls
```