# How to get image url in vue from django rest project

Tags: vuejs2, django-rest-framework

I stored image file in path djangor_prject_name/pictures/image_name.jpg by using

```
models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/services/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

and file is uploaded successfully.
But while retrieving, what is the exact url to view image?
Because id Database, the value is just

```
picutes/services/image_name.jpg
```

So, in my view file, I am using vue.js and need full path or url of the image to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creation it won't give you full url, but in the list it will come with full url. So for that you use custom [serializers.SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('photo',) 

    def get_photo(self, car):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        photo = Test.photo.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(photo)
```

For further details [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522768/django-serializer-imagefield-to-get-full-url)